# PDFkit is not applying bootsrap CSS

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I am Working on converting HTML to PDF, My HTML contains the bootstrap classes:

I have tried two approaches:

1. Using PDFkit
2. weasyprint

Following is my HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="pdfcss.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
  <p>The columns will automatically stack on top of each other when the screen is less than 768px wide.</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Using PDKkit :

```
import pdfkit
css = 'pdfcss.css'
pdfkit.from_file('test_test.html', '/tmp/out.pdf',css=css)
```

Got Following Result as PDF[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6EA0.png)

By Using weasyprint:

```
from weasyprint import HTML, CSS
HTML(string='<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head> <title>Bootstrap Example</title> <meta charset="utf-8"> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> <link rel="stylesheet" href=""> </head> <body> <div class="container-fluid"> <h1>Hello World!</h1> <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p> <p>The columns will automatically stack on top of each other when the screen is less than 768px wide.</p> <div class="row"> <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div> <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-4</div> <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div> </div> </div> </body> </html>').write_pdf("/tmp/out.pdf", stylesheets=['/var/www/html/NTAsset-Repo/NtAsset/NtAseetWepApp/website/static/pdfcss.css'])
```

In both cases CSS is not get applied to PDF,

Kindly help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

add `!important` to the background style. For example:

```html
<div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender !important;">.col-sm-4</div>
```